# How do I recover an object if I didn't def it?

Tags: clojure

I am using Clojure in a REPL. Suppose I execute something like (read-line) which returns a string object, but I don't do anything like (def x (read-line)) which would save that string object anywhere specific.

Is the object hanging around somewhere where I can recover it, and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last three results are bound to `*1`, `*2` and `*3` and the last exception to `*e` e.g.

```
> (read-line)
> hello world

> *1
"hello world"
```

Comment: Once you've typed four more commands (so the object of interest has been pushed out of *1, *2 and *3) is there any way to recover a reference to it?

Comment: The repl doesn't save everything indefinitely, no. Garbage collection couldn't work, if there were a way for you to "resurrect" any value you once had a reference to.